# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class

Tags: android

I am creating an app in which I want to open an Image slider in popup when an image I click from gallery view.But I getting Following error. 
I look for this error in stackoverflow but didnt found the reason of getting this error.
Error:

```
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106): Process: info.androidhive.listviewfeed, PID: 14106
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class info.androidhive.imageslider.helper.TouchImageView
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.FullScreenImageAdapter.instantiateItem(FullScreenImageAdapter.java:52)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2252)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1283)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.imageslider.helper.TouchImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.androidhive.listviewfeed-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/info.androidhive.listviewfeed-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
11-15 14:17:58.945: E/AndroidRuntime(14106):    ... 42 more
```

Here is the class to call a pagerview

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

File directory;

public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
    TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
    NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Gallery feedImageView = (Gallery) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

    FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

    name.setText(item.getName());

    // Converting timestamp into x ago format


    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();      
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int timeAgo = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) + c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) +      c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    directory = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + File.separator + "niece");

if (directory.isDirectory()) {
// getting list of file paths
File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

// Check for count
if (listFiles.length > 0) {

    // loop through all files
    for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

        // get file path
        String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

        // check for supported file extension

            filePaths.add(filePath);
    }
   } else {
    // image directory is empty
    Toast.makeText(
            activity,
            "niece is empty. Please load some images in it !",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

 } else {
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
alert.setTitle("Error!");
alert.setMessage("niece directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class");
alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
alert.show();
 }

    // Chcek for empty status message
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
        statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Checking for null feed url
    if (item.getUrl() != null) {
        url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

        // Making url clickable
        url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // url is null, remove from the view
        url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // user profile pic
    profilePic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // Feed image
    if (item.getImge() != null) {
        feedImageView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    feedImageView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Dialog popImg = new Dialog(activity);
            popImg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            popImg.setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) popImg.findViewById(R.id.pager);

            popImg.setTitle("Testing");
            adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(activity,
                    filePaths);

            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            // displaying selected image first
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            popImg.show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}}
```

Here is the pageviewer class

```
import info.androidhive.listviewfeed.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

 public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

// constructor
public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TouchImageView imgDisplay;
    Button btnClose;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,false);

    imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    // close button click event
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _activity.finish();
        }
    }); 

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
```

}

TouchImageView class

```
package info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(curr);
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                    float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                            origWidth * saveScale);
                    float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                            origHeight * saveScale);
                    matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                    fixTrans();
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                    performClick();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                    viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
            * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
          if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
    fixTrans();
}
}
```

activityfullscreenview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
```

layoutfullscreenimage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<info.androidhive.imageslider.helper.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"

    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Close" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your `TouchImageView` class also.

Comment: show your xml and also mention package name..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you add `info.androidhive.imageslider.helper.TouchImageView` in your `layout_fullscreen_image` xml file but your `TouchImageView` is in `info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter` package.So in  `layout_fullscreen_image` file change

```
info.androidhive.imageslider.helper.TouchImageView
```

to

```
info.androidhive.listviewfeed.adapter.TouchImageView
```

Comment: @NeeravShah happy to help,enjoy.

Comment: i knew this is the problem so i asked to post xml.. anyways your issue solved.. :)